# After fresh installation of SharePoint master page and default page is not displaying properly

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2012. I have installed the SQL evaluation version on Windows Server.

After a successfull installation the default page is not displaying properly. It shows some basic HTML format. Please find the attached img.

Please help me in resolving this problem. 
[image]

Comment: Is it browser specific? Or just in IE?

Comment: Dear Robert Lindgren, Thanks for the reply. I tried on chrome,friefox and IE. In all browsers same error, page is not loading properly. Is this requires license version of visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Do iisreset and try once again.

Comment: Dear Martusha, This did not help.Still facing the same problem. Looks like the problem is that when it try to load the imgs it retruns http status code 500 when I checked in fidder tool. Please help me how to solve this. Waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your IE version? 
Do you open Cenral Administration from server or from your pc?
Check also hard disk space available on C disk

Answer (score 0):

1. Disable IE Enhanced Security on Windows Server, instructions [here](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/11/28/how-to-disable-ie-enhanced-security-in-windows-server-2012/)
2. Enusure site is in Trusted Sites in IE

Comment: Dear Jussi Palo, This did not help.Still facing the same problem. Looks like the problem is that when it try to load the imgs it retruns http status code 500 when I checked in fidder tool. Please help me how to solve this. Waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance